# Is it valid to use test-set performance (RMSEP) to choose between models with similar RMSECVs?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

Say I run k-fold cross validation with a number of different regression methods in an effort to determine which method is best for my data. At the end of running cross validation, I have RMSECVs for each method and for some of the methods the RMSECVs are very similar - close enough that I don't think there's a meaningful difference. (I could use a statistical test to make this determination of "similarity" more rigorous, but that's a separate topic...)

I also have a test set: data that was not included in any of the cross validation. What I am wondering is whether it is valid to use the test set results (the RMSEP) to choose from among the models with very similar RMSECVs, or is that still considered to be biasing the results and giving an overly optimistic estimate of the performance on truly unknown data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is valid to use the test set results (the RMSEP) to choose from among the models with very similar RMSECVs, or is that still considered to be biasing the results and giving an overly optimistic estimate of the performance on truly unknown data?

Yes to both:

- there's nothing to keep you from taking different figures of merit into account for choosing the model. The particular set you propose here probably won't help, though (see below)
- But then of course you optimize on the test set, and if you need an unbiased performance estimate, you need to get a set of truly unknown data, i.e. yet another test set.

---

That being said, I doubt that selecting on a (single) test set will help compared to selecting based on $RMSE_{CV}$ unless your train/test split is better (in achieving independence) than the cross validation splits. This can happen in practice, e.g. you have clustered/hierarchical data structure/repeated measurements and the test set comes from an independently prepared/collected set of samples whereas the cross validation splits did not account for this structure in your data. (The obvious objection would be that the cross validation splitting should be fixed instead)

If you do not have such a peculiar situation where you suspect or even know that the cross validation splitting is worse than the train/test splitting:

- Then your $RMSE_{CV}$ is typically based on more test cases $RMSE_{P}$ (because typically only a small fraction of the whole data set is reserved for testing).
- This means that $RMSE_{P}$'s uncertainty (variance) due to test sample size is larger than the correspondig variance on $RMSE_{CV}$.
- You'd therefore have to expect $RMSE_{P}$ to be a *worse* optimization criterion than $RMSE_{CV}$.

So in other words, the proposed procedure would at least under the typical assumptions for splitting being rather a waste of samples.

---

I'd recommend to look at the situation the other way round.

- You found a range of your hyperparamters that give equally good performance?
  Fine! You found not only "the optimum" but actually found that this optimum is stable wrt. the actual choice of the hyperparameter values. Which is even better.
- You found that PLSR, PCR and ridge regression achieve equal performance?
  Fine. The conclusion is that regularized linear regression is suitable. (I'd be more worried if I observe PCR grossly outperforming PLSR and ridge)